Get access to children numeric position within parent component(#1, #2,...) | Reactjs
I'm looking for a way to get access to position of each child component within it's parent
I have a component called Slider which can have multiple child components. lets call them SliderSection and each SliderSection can have multiple SliderStep components.
It looks something like this:
   <Slider>
      <SliderSection>
        <SliderStep>step 1</SliderStep>
        <SliderStep>step 2</SliderStep>
        <SliderStep>step 3</SliderStep>
      </SliderSection>
      <SliderSection>
        <SliderStep>step 1</SliderStep>
      </SliderSection>
      <SliderSection>
        <SliderStep>step 1</SliderStep>
        <SliderStep>step 2</SliderStep>
      </SliderSection>
   </Slider>

there is a functionality inside both SliderSection and SliderStep which rely on the position of them inside the parent component(Slider)
i used to pass down their position number as a prop to each component like this:
by using props called sectionNum and stepNum
 <Slider>
      <SliderSection sectionNum={1}>
        <SliderStep stepNum={1}></SliderStep>
        <SliderStep stepNum={2}></SliderStep>
        <SliderStep stepNum={3}></SliderStep>
      </SliderSection>
      <SliderSection sectionNum={2}>
        <SliderStep stepNum={1}></SliderStep>
      </SliderSection>
      <SliderSection sectionNum={3}>
        <SliderStep stepNum={1}></SliderStep>
        <SliderStep stepNum={2}></SliderStep>
      </SliderSection>
    </Slider>

notice how sectionNum starts from 1 and goes up for each SliderSection, sliderNum also starts from 1 and goes up for each SliderStep inside SliderSection and resets to 1 when SliderSection changes and goes up.(basically first step of each section stepNum is 1)
but this has some consequences beside not being automatic.
how can i get access to positions without manually passing props down?
why do i need this info inside SliderStep and SliderSection components?:
I want to be able to return null depending on some values(ex, don't render step 2 if x is true) but since the sectionNum and stepNum props are hardcoded it will mess up the indexing of the slider so i need a way to handle this even if for example section#1-step#2 is not rendered internationally section#1-step#3 should change to section#1-step#2

You can't access the parent directly from a component, but you can have the parent use React.Children.map and React.cloneElement to inject the index prop to each child before rendering them.
import React from "react";

function Slider({ children }) {
  const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(children, (child, index) =>
    React.cloneElement(child, { index }),
  );
  return <div>{childrenWithProps}</div>;
}

function SliderSection({ children, index }) {
  const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(children, (child, index) =>
    React.cloneElement(child, { index }),
  );
  return (
    <div>
      Section {index}
      <br />
      {childrenWithProps}
    </div>
  );
}

function SliderStep({ children, index }) {
  return (
    <div>
      Step {index}: {children}
    </div>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Slider>
      <SliderSection>
        <SliderStep>step 1</SliderStep>
        <SliderStep>step 2</SliderStep>
        <SliderStep>step 3</SliderStep>
      </SliderSection>
      <SliderSection>
        <SliderStep>step 1</SliderStep>
      </SliderSection>
      <SliderSection>
        <SliderStep>step 1</SliderStep>
        <SliderStep>step 2</SliderStep>
      </SliderSection>
    </Slider>
  );
}

renders
Section 0
Step 0: step 1
Step 1: step 2
Step 2: step 3
Section 1
Step 0: step 1
Section 2
Step 0: step 1
Step 1: step 2


thank you so much. i thought about using Children, but since React docs are heavily against recommending it i never used it. Does this have any negative impact on overall performance?

One way to find out: measure it. I don't think it will have a very heavy effect, anyway.
